# Viewing the contents of an IMG file

Tags: boot, retropie, image

I have an retroPi img file that I wanted to view the contents for. I've burned the contents onto an SD card and when my Mac mounts the volume, I only see 50 or so megabytes worth of content, yet when I boot it up in the Raspberry Pi, I can play gigs and gigs worth of roms.

Where is all this content hidden? Is there any way to view the contents of the IMG file properly? How does this all work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`macOS` can't (actually won't) show Linux `ext4` partitions. There used to be 3rd party software to mount these, but Apple are making it more difficult with each new release.

You can see the contents on any Linux OS.

Comment: Windows also only shows the 1st partition (boot) and hides the others with the standard explorer (disk management will show other partitions)

Comment: @user2813274 What does what Windows do or not do have to do with the Mac?

Comment: Was just a fyi if you wanted to make the answer more general